# How to get header response in Retrofit in Android?

Tags: android, retrofit

This is my end point :

```
@POST("v4/MyStore/data")
Observable<Headers> requestStore(@Body MyStoreRequest request);
```

I am trying to get response like this :

```
requestService.requestStore(request)
                .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
                .observeOn(Schedulers.computation())
                .map(headers -> {
                   Log.d("Response",""+headers);
                    return headers;
                }).subscribe(headers -> {
                            Log.d("Response",""+headers);
                        },
                        error -> {
                           Log.d("ERRRROOOR","Error");
                        });
```

I am getting error like below:

```
Exception: retrofit2.adapter.rxjava.HttpException: HTTP 403 Forbidden
```

While in postman I am getting response:

```
Connection →keep-alive
Content-Length →0
Content-Type →application/json; charset=utf-8
Date →Mon, 03 Sep 2018 18:47:30 GMT
MYid →f028df50-c8c5-4cce-92e7-70130345ba46
```

What I am doing wrong here?

Comment: Are you trying this in your WAMP Server?

Comment: no this SqlServer

Comment: Okay, Someone will help you with this. All the best.

Comment: @UmangBurman i am also getting  'this' is not available”

Comment: I know about 403 forbidden for WAMP, you have to make some setting allowance in their server. Something like Grant All permission. But, I do not have any idea about SqlServer. Sorry

Comment: but in postman i am getting correct response @UmangBurman

Comment: Yeah postman is built up to deal with such conditions, it will automatically apply the necessary conditions. Someone good in SQLServer will definitely know about it.

Comment: @AnilThakur your question is not complete enough to understand the problem correctly. Please [edit] and add these information. **1**. Which environment you're using for server, C#? **2**. Trying in LAN or live server? **3**. If using IIS server, is it configured to access it in LAN? **4**. Sample of the (JSON?) body you send to server and expected output. **5**. Finally [mcve] (Currently posted code is not enough. Do not post complete code only the minimal code. If anyone wants clarification, they'll ask for further codes)

Comment: @Shashanth in postman i am getting correct response  if you want i can send you request and response  body in post method we are sending {
  "StoreRequestId" : "mnsa990jas",
  "stateOfStore" : "notComleted"
}   and also header in request : Authorization:Bearer ca0df98d-978c-410b-96ec-4e592a788c18
Content-Type:application/json in Response i am getting                        HTTP/1.1 202 OK
Date: Tue, 04 Sep 2018 04:18:34 GMT
Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8
Content-Length: 0
Connection: open
ID: 88773hhf i want use this in  code . please help

Answer (score 2):

You have to use a Response as your response model because your api is entering error stream in with a code 403

```
 @POST("v4/MyStore/data")
 Observable<Response<Void>> requestStore(@Body MyStoreRequest request);
```

now when you consume response

```
 requestService.requestStore(request)
            .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
            .observeOn(Schedulers.computation())
            .map(response -> {
               Log.d("Response",""+response);
                return response.header();
            }).subscribe(headers -> {
                        Log.d("Response",""+headers);
                    },
                    error -> {
                       Log.d("ERRRROOOR","Error");
                    });
```

**response.header()** will return you the header you want even when your api fails

Comment: i need simple that response Header in retrofit how to call Response Header in retorfit

Comment: response.getHeaders(); should give you the response header.

Comment: Observable<Headers> . here we need to change it ? Observable<Response>

Answer (score 0):

Probably you're missing headers in your API request from Android client. As per your [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52155369/how-to-get-header-response-in-retrofit-in-android#comment91267406_52155369), you're sending bearer token in Authorization headers.

So, you need to send bearer token along with request body like below

```
@Headers({
        "Authorization: Bearer <your_bearer_token_here>", /* change token here */
        "Content-Type: application/json"
})
@POST("v4/MyStore/data")
Observable<Headers> requestStore(@Body MyStoreRequest request);
```

Example,

```
@Headers({
        "Authorization: Bearer ca0df98d-978c-410b-96ec-4e592a788c18",
        "Content-Type: application/json"
})
@POST("v4/MyStore/data")
Observable<Headers> requestStore(@Body MyStoreRequest request);
```

Comment: no in request its going Header  i am checking it in Charles